# C++ if/else undeclared identifier, trying to use words

Tags: c++, if-statement, undeclared-identifier

I'm trying to make a little game, and I'm a beginner.

The problem is the parts with the ifs and the else, where it says "Lady" and "Sir".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    string playerName;
    int age;
    int playerGender;

    cout << "Are you a Lady or a Sir?" << endl;
    cin >> playerGender;

    if (playerGender = Lady)
    {
    cout << "So you're a girl. " << endl;
    }
    else if (playerGender = Sir)
    {
    cout << "So you're a boy." << endl;
    }
    cout << "What is your name " << playerGender << "?" << endl;
    cin >> playerName;

    cout << "What is your age?" << playerName << endl;
    cin >> age;

    if (age <= 10)
    {
    cout << "You're too young " << playerName << "! " << endl;
    }
    else if (age >= 11)
    {
    cout << "You are old enough to play" << playerName << ". " << endl;
```

That's what I have, I don't know whats wrong. Help please!

Comment: `playerGender = Lady` is an assignment not an equality check. Also what/where is "Lady" defined (or are they strings to check against but you forgot the quotes - but playerGender is an `int` not a string...?)

Comment: What @john3136 means is that, assuming that a "Lady" is an actual defined thing, you would want that to be `if (playerGender == Lady)...`

Comment: What actually happens when you try to compile? What errors or warnings do you see?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2065 'Sir': undeclared identifier Hello World 
 and

Comment: Too many silly typos and mistakes to count. Take more care!

Answer (score 1):

When you perform the following:

```
std::cin >> playerGender;
```

You are retrieving a **number** from the user. You are then **assigning** that number to your `playerGender` with the following:

```
if (playerGender = Lady)
```

You're only using a single `=`, which **assigns** the value that's in `Lady` to `playerGender`. You probably mean to write `==` which will **compare** the value of `playerGender` and `Lady`.

I can't tell what `Lady` and `Sir` are, but for your purposes you will need to ensure they are an `int`:

```
const int Lady = 0, Sir = 1;
```

**Or** an `enum`:

```
enum genders { Lady = 0, Sir = 1 };
```

Now you can make the following **comparison**:

```
if (playerGender == Lady)
{
}
else if (playerGender == Sir)
{
}
```